# set the date and time to current date and time

Tags: javascript, html

I want to limit the user from selecting the current date and current time.

What I have tried is:

```
<input id="datefield" type="date" />
<input type="time" id="timefield" class="form-control" />
```

```
var today = new Date();
var thishr = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

var hr = today.getHours();
var mn = today.getMinutes();

if(dd < 10){
    dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10){
    mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
thishr = hr + '-' + mn;

document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

document.getElementById("timefield").setAttribute("max", thishr);
document.getElementById("timefield").setAttribute("min", thishr);
```

Seems like the JavaScript for the date part is working, but the part for the time is not working as expected. Did I miss some important part?

Comment: are you saying you DO NOT want the user to choose the CORRECT date and time?

Comment: I want to restrict the user to select the current time (example (5/17/2022 7:55). since the date and time are will be used for visitor login time , so the user should not be input any time they want

Answer (score 0):

**first:**

`hr` and `mn` have to include leading zeros, and the separator should be a colon, not a hyphen. like this : `"08:05"`.

**second**:

put your input into a `form` element with a submit button. you will still be able to select any time, but when you will try to submit the form, the validation won't let you if the selected time is out of range.